# Java: summarize data with streams

Tags: java, list, filter, stream

Is it possible to summarize values with streams? For example, I have a class Dataset that divides a csv file for me into lines that contain values:

```
{customer=Max , articlenr=1234, paid=12}
{customer=Lisa , articlenr=21, paid=20}
{customer=Max , articlenr=19, paid=100}
```

Now I want to create a List with a Stream which gives me a list of my customers back(no other values), sorted by the sum what they have ever paid (in this example Max has paid 112 and Lisa 20).
So I would expect getting Max first in the List and the Lisa.

Comment: Do you want just the "customer" field, so a list like `["Max", "Lisa"]`?

Comment: Thats correct. So if Lisa has paid more then Max I would like to get ["Lisa", "Max"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the sum of `paid` to a `Map<String, Integer>`, then stream the entries, sorting them in reverse order by paid, then collect the keys to a `List`.

```
List<MyClass> records; // your list

List<String> customers = records.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(MyClass::getCustomer, Collectors.summingInt(MyClass::getPaid)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible:

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private int articlenr;
    private int paid;
}
```

Now, you can use like this to get the list of names, ordered by the total paid first:

```
List<String> names = customerList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Customer::getPaid)).map(Customer::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I wrote an article a few days on how to use Streams and some more examples: http://petrepopescu.tech/2021/01/simple-collection-manipulation-in-java-using-lambdas/

Comment: This totally misses the point of the question. This returns every record sorted by paid, so you'll get `["Max", "Lisa", "Max"]`, but OP wants `["Max", "Lisa"]` - each name *once* sorted by *total* paid highest to lowest.

Comment: Correct. I thought that the paid variable has the total and that the names are unique. My bad. Your answer is the correct one.